# Python: why my original list is affected after updating copied list

Tags: python, list, copy

```py
twoSeq=[['28.406925,77.285590', '28.409969,77.292279'],
    ['28.406925,77.285590', '28.402476,77.292956'],
    ['28.409969,77.292279', '28.403020,77.298851'],
    ['28.403020,77.298851', '28.392363,77.306091'],
    ['28.392363,77.306091', '28.378515,77.313990'],
    ['28.378515,77.313990', '28.367469,77.315308'],
    ['28.402476,77.292956', '28.399600,77.297313'],
    ['28.402476,77.292956', '28.397301,77.294096'],
    ['28.399600,77.297313', '28.392247,77.301909'],
    ['28.392247,77.301909', '28.392363,77.306091'],
    ['28.397301,77.294096', '28.399600,77.297313']]

def N_Seq(twoSeq):
    first=twoSeq.copy()
    last=twoSeq.copy()

    for i in range(len(first)):
        first[i].pop(0)
    print(first,"--------")
    for j in range(len(last)): 
        last[j].pop() 
    print(first)
N_Seq(twoSeq)
```

---

Output:

```py
[['28.409969,77.292279'], ['28.402476,77.292956'], ['28.403020,77.298851'], ['28.392363,77.306091'], ['28.378515,77.313990'], ['28.367469,77.315308'], ['28.399600,77.297313'], ['28.397301,77.294096'], ['28.392247,77.301909'], ['28.392363,77.306091'], ['28.399600,77.297313']] --------
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: you are creating a shallow copy. use `copy.deepcopy`

Answer (score 4):

[`list.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) creates a shallow copy of the list. This means that it creates a new list and inserts references to items into it. In this case you should use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), which returns a deep copy.

From the documentation:

> The difference between shallow and deep copying is only relevant for compound objects
> (objects that contain other objects, like lists or class instances):
>
> - A *shallow copy* constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible)
>   inserts *references* into it to the objects found in the original.
> - A *deep copy* constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts *copies*
>   into it of the objects found in the original.

Answer (score 2):

**Shallow list copy**

A shallow copy only copies the list itself, which is a container of references to the objects in the list. If the objects contained themselves are mutable and one is changed, the change will be reflected in both lists.

**Deep copy**

The deep copied list is an entirely different list from the original.

```
import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

For [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import copy
twoSeq=[['28.406925,77.285590', '28.409969,77.292279'],
['28.406925,77.285590', '28.402476,77.292956'],
['28.409969,77.292279', '28.403020,77.298851'],
['28.403020,77.298851', '28.392363,77.306091'],
['28.392363,77.306091', '28.378515,77.313990'],
['28.378515,77.313990', '28.367469,77.315308'],
['28.402476,77.292956', '28.399600,77.297313'],
['28.402476,77.292956', '28.397301,77.294096'],
['28.399600,77.297313', '28.392247,77.301909'],
['28.392247,77.301909', '28.392363,77.306091'],
['28.397301,77.294096', '28.399600,77.297313']]

def N_Seq(twoSeq):
    first=copy.deepcopy(twoSeq)
    last=copy.deepcopy(twoSeq)

    for i in range(len(first)):
        first[i].pop(0)
    print(first,"--------")
    for j in range(len(last)): 
        last[j].pop() 
    print(first)
N_Seq(twoSeq)
```